# How to duplicate docker image with a new tag?

Tags: docker

Let's say I have an image with tag `:latest`.
I'd like to duplicate the image on my PC and then give it another tag like `:1.4.2`

I do not want to build the image, just copy and retag it.

Comment: You can just [`docker tag`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) it with the new label.  You can't duplicate it, but you also can't change the image in any way (beyond relabelling it) so it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Docker tagging works as an effective copy You reference a new image (as listed via `docker images`) with tag `:1.4.2`  which maps to the same IMAGE_ID as the  `:latest` one. If you rebuuild your image, latest will be updated and refer to a new IMAGE_ID, but `:1.4.2`  will still exist with the previous IMAGE_ID.

Answer (score 11):

I occasionally need to clone docker images that clients are using as a backup when they want to try a new version. This provides them the option of easily reverting if needed.

assuming your image is called `best-ui` and has the tag `latest` we will clone this with the tag `old`

```
docker tag best-ui:latest best-ui:old
```

now run `docker images` and you will see the new cloned image with the new tag

Comment: Can you explain why you used a different name `detect-ui`?

Comment: @JustTheHighlights - yes it was a typo - ive edited the post

Answer (score 1):

**You can duplicate a docker image then change its IMAGE ID :**

(1) run as per above :

**docker tag best-ui:latest best-ui:old**

This will create two images with same IMAGE ID - but different tags.

(2) Start up a container using the best-ui:latest  image ( i.e. start up the copy of original image )

**docker   run   --ipc=host   -it    best-ui:latest**

(3) Change something inside the container ( e.g. duplicate a file inside the container - just so long as something has definitely changed ) - this will alter the hash of the container.

(4) Commit changes to the container while its running , but do this outside the container, from another command/terminal window on your current machine/host where the container is running.

**docker commit <12_digit_string_shown_after_"@root"_in_Container>  best-ui:latest**

(5) Run :

**docker images**

to see that the copy of the image has changed its IMAGE ID.

Done  :-)

Answer (score -6):

You can use the save command to export the image,

`docker save -o (name of file).tar (add an image name during the export here)`

When this has been completed, you can load the exported image,

`docker load -i (name of file).tar`

to complete the copy of the image.

Comment: this has nothing to with the question